# Syntax error with use of pipe in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, heredoc

I'm diving headfirst into bash with no prior experience and have hit a bit of a snag: I wrote a small bash script to determine the average of values (it's just a total right now) being returned by a c executable.

```
#Sample value of #s1total: 0+0.000117+0.000149+0.000106

printf "\n%s" $s1total

#The following line works
printf "\nTotal: %s\n" $(bc <<< $s1total)

#the following also works
echo
echo -n "Total: "
echo $s1total | bc

#The following line does not work
printf "\nTotal: %s\n" $($s1total|bc)
```

I did eventually find that the last line can be made to work by changing it to `$(echo $s1total|bc)` but i don't understand why that works ...

If I run as-is, I get an error:`./sievetest.sh: line 25: 0+0.000117+0.000149+0.000106: command not found`

Is the string being run before the pipe? Why? Why does adding "echo" fix it?
How is the third method different than the first and second?

(as an aside, I thought the heredoc redirection operator was << , why the extra < ?)

Comment: there are various type of heredoc. `<<<` has a special meaning of, consider the following string as input. so you don't see `<<EOF EOF` type of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this:

```
$($s1total|bc)
```

which is basically

```
$(0+0.000117+0.000149+0.000106 | bc)
```

e.g. run a command named `0+....` and pipe it to `bc`.

It should be

```
$(echo $s1total|bc)
```

Comment: So ... pipe is essentially taking a stdout from the first command and redirecting it to the stdin to the target command, whereas <<< is redirecting a string(or another stream?) to the stdin of the target?

Comment: `<<<` *only* redirects a string to standard input (it's a `bash` shortcut for a one-line here document).